# Что такое артефакт (artifact) в контексте языка Java?

Tags: java, терминология, артефакты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что такое артефакт (artifact) в контексте языка Java?

Так же интересно чем Артефакты(Artifacts) отличаются от библиотек(Libraries) в настройках проекта.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Артефакты не относятся к языку Java, а являются результатом вашей работы.

> Артефакт - это сборка активов вашего проекта, которые вы собрали для
>   тестирования, развертывания или распространения вашего программного
>   решения или его части. Примерами являются набор скомпилированных
>   классов Java или приложения Java, упакованных в архив Java,
>   веб-приложение в виде структуры каталогов или архива веб-приложений и
>   т. д.

Библиотеки же являются зависимостями, которые используются вашей программой в работе, и сделаны кем то другим.

Вы можете сколько угодно работать над проектом не генерируя ни одного артефакта. Но вряд ли у вас что то получиться, если вы не подключили нужные вам библиотеки, или подключили неподходящую версию.

Comment: Получается, что то, что подключено в библиотеках проекта используется для реализации функционала самого приложения, а то что в артефактах используется для реализации вспомогательного (аспектного) функционала.. я правильно понял?

Comment: Вряд ли тестирование или развертывание можно назвать вспомогательным функционалом. Это совершенно разные аспекты работы над проектом. Но если так говорить, библиотеки и правда обеспечивают функционал самого приложения, а артефакты - рабочий процесс, некий жизненный цикл разработки, когда ваше приложение, существующее в начале только в виде кода на вашем компьютере вдруг должно начать взаимодействовать с внешним миром.

Comment: благодарю за разъяснения!

Comment: Допустим что у меня в jar есть набор классов для тестирования. я могу их подключить как в библиотеки так и в артефакты. в чем будет разница как их подключать?

Comment: Вам нужно подключить их как библиотеку.  Вы получите возможность пользоваться этой библиотекой, в приложении (в т.ч. тестировать). А подключив как артефакт -  возможность сбилдить свой артефакт из чужого кода? Артефакт это не готовый внешний модуль, а то, во что будет преобразовано ваше приложение или его часть после команды `Build`.

Answer (score 2):

Артефакты - в широком смысле это некие объекты создаваемые в ходе разработки ПО, например схемы классов, объектные коды, документация, инструкции, иконки, картинки и проч. все что сопровождает процесс разработки.

В узком смысле - в смысле Intellij IDEA это некая выходная сборка вашего проекта. В общем случае их может быть несколько: `jar` для десктопа и `.war` для веба ну и т.д.

Для каждого артефакта можно определить правила сборки, развертывания, запуска и т.д.

Есть еще артефакты в смысле Maven - это все тот же архив, но предназначенный для деплоймента на репозиторий maven

В самом собственно Java нет понятия артефакта - артефакт продукт среды/средства разработки.

Comment: благодарю за разъяснения. Вы указали что в контексте Intellij IDEA артефакт это выходная сборка моего проекта. Зачем тогда в IDEA в структуре проекта эта кнопка для подключения артефактов? (Для чего мне к моему проекту подключать свой же проект?)

Comment: @AndreyZinovich , возможно не свой же проект, а другой проект-артефакт (но это только предположение)